# Transformar Excel en JSON con JavaCompute en IBM ACE

Tags: json

Alguno tiene un ejemplo simple para leer una tabla de excel (no CSV) y transformarlo en JSON a traves de un nodo JavaCompute en IBM ACE?

He probado de varias maneras, pero me retorna null la linea de codigo:

```java
String excelFilePath = (String) inAssembly.getLocalEnvironment().getRootElement().getFirstElementByPath("File/InputFile/Name").getValue();
```

El Excel se lee desde un nodo FileInput, se procesa en el nodo JavaCompute, y el JSON se envía en un nodo FileOutput